# change hint Text position in Text field with expands in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, styles, textfield, type-hinting

I have Text field which will take a long message from the user and I set **expands** to True

the problem is the hint text is not at the beginning of the the line, How do I change its position ?

[image]

```
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: CustomTextField(
                enabledRadius: 7,
                focusedRadius: 7,
                expands: true,
                hintText: 'message',
                controller: messageController,
                textInputType: TextInputType.multiline,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I figured it out by using

```
 textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical(y: -1),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use `textAlign:TextAlign.start` to align the hint
```

Here see the full code:

```
 SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: CustomTextField(
                enabledRadius: 7,
                focusedRadius: 7,
                expands: true,
                maxLines: null,
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                hintText: 'message',
                controller: messageController,
                textInputType: TextInputType.multiline,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customise `TextFormField` by using these properties.

```
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                           border: InputBorder.none,
                           focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                           enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                           errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                           disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                           hintText: '0',
                           counterText: '',
                           hintStyle: TextStyle(
                           color: greyPlaceholderColor,
                           fontSize: fontSize40,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
```